# If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}$ is given by $f(x,y) = (3x + 1, 2y - 3)$, then find if it is bijective and if so, give the inverse.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In order to prove it is bijective, I go about trying to prove injective and surjective.

I think I have proved that this is 1-1. 
I did, $(3x_1 + 1) = (3x_2 +1)$ and also $(2y_1 - 3) = (2y_2 - 3)$
I solved both of these to get $x_1 = x_2$ and also $y_1 = y_2$.

Now I'm on the (onto) part of this and I'm really lost. I know there was a question already like this but I didn't understand the solution. I need this explained like I am a baby.

Comment: You correctly showed it was 1-1. To show it is onto, you need to show that every element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is mapped to by something from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Basically, can we get every real number in the the $x$ slot and every real number in the $y$ slot from plugging something into the function?

Comment: Note that this is a linear function (or transformation) from $\Bbb R^2$ to itself; so if you've taken linear algebra, you can use your linear algebra intuition.

Comment: @pjs36 It is not a linear transformation in the sense of linear or vector spaces as it doesn't map zero to zero. It though is a map with linear coordinates.

Comment: Good point, @Joanpemo, I should have been more careful, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathStack exchange here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: @Arbuja Thanks, I was wondering about that.

Comment: @pjs36: for future reference, this function is the composite of a translation ($(x, y) \mapsto (x +1, y -3)$) and a linear transformation ($(x, y) \mapsto (3x, 2y)$). Such functions are called *affine* functions. (And, for the OP, it is often easier to answer questions like yours by looking at the linear transformation and the translation separately.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah that simplifies it in my head, thanks

Answer (score 3):

For any $\;(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2\;$ :

$$\begin{cases}a=3x+1\iff x=\frac{a-1}3\\{}\\b=2y-3\iff y=\frac{b+3}2\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\;\;f\left(\frac{a-1}3,\,\frac{b+3}2\right)=(a,b)$$